# Numbers Relation Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence, calculation-puzzle

I've written a numbers relation puzzle, I'd like to share it with you and see what you fellas think.

------
Try to find the relation between the numbers------

**Good to know:** there are 2 parameters involved in the equation.
1,7 = 7
3,5 = 405
2,3 = 12
4,6 = 24576
3,9 =

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is

> $3,9 = 729$

Reasoning

> It looks like $$a,b = a^{2a-2} \times b$$ so that $$3,9 = 3^4 \times 9 = 729$$

Comment: Correct. good job !

Comment: If they've done of good job, @Uniqueflave, please accept their answer